# Generate UV maps for geometry node curves

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create hair curves using geometry nodes rather than profile curves, so that I can have more control over certain parameters as can be seen below (like making the segments equally spaced, with an arbitrary resolution for length and points on the circle)

I am however running into the issue of texturing/shading, as I don't know **how to generate the UVs in the same manner as the profile curve does automatically**.

How can I do this? Thanks!

[image: Geo-Node Hair (Left) Curve with profile (Right)]
^^Both are made from a path curve. The one on the right has a curve circle set as the bevel object, and the shaders work nicely as can be seen. The one on the left is resampled and generated with the node setup below and has 0 UV area
[image: Geo-Node Setup]
^^Setup for the hair strand on the left: Just resamples the input path and generates a mesh with a profile circle with global parameters to have all hair "strands" be equally detailed

[image: Profile Curve Setup]

^^Setup for the hair strand on the right
[image: Simple Hair Shader]
^^Basic Shader

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy to do. Just use the `Factor` of the Profile for the `X`, and the `Factor` of the Curve for the `Y`:

[image: Blender node setup for UV Map]

Now you can map the UV output to the UVMap attribute:

[image: Blender set UVMap attribute]

And you can access the UVMap attribute inside of your shader material by using an `Attribute` node:

[image: Blender shader Attribute node]