# Getting Uneven UV for Curve in Geometry Nodes with Capturing Attributes

Tags: uv, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, procedural

I've seen this questions posted in places before, but haven't found an easy workaround yet. There's [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258246/curve-to-mesh-with-uvs-in-blender-3-x) but it's kind of complex...

The standard way to do this as mentioned in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268781/generate-uv-maps-for-geometry-node-curves) thread is to use capture attribute. I have a simple Curve to Mesh setup that uses this method:
[image]

Is there a simple way to just make this UV 'even'? Because the logic should be there, but not sure why one part of the seem is just super compact and disconnected...

Hope someone can give an answer to this, or maybe improve this in a new update :3

Comment: I am currently working on a simpler solution regarding the question you linked. Have a little patience, I will publish it soon.

Comment: It looks like your curve is a vertical line that you bevel with a circle, making a vertical wire, and you want to make the UV of the caps even?